# MessageBox fails with multiple unhandled async exceptions

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, exception, async-await

We have a fairly large WPF Prism application that makes heavy use of the async-await pattern.

I have also implemented a global exception handler that shows a MessageBox and gracefully shuts down the app, using all the events as follows.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
DispatcherUnhandledException += App_DispatcherUnhandledException;
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;
```

When I get one exception at a time it works quite nicely and lets developers know right away when they get some synchronization logic wrong.  But we had a problem spot where 3 unhandled exeptions were coming out of separate async void event handlers.

2 unhandled events meant that MessageBox.Show would actually fail by throwing one of the completely unrelated previous exceptions, as if the UI thread had given up and just pulled the last exception off a queue.  The DispatcherUnhandledException would only fire once.

The 3rd exception would then go to Current.Domain.UnhandledException and cause an unhandled crash because at that point I've already tried to shutdown the app.

So I guess my question is has anyone seen this behavior before?  Can you point me to any resources to explain better how multiple exceptions are handled by the Dispatcher?  Ideally I just want to catch the first and throw the rest away, but the second exception prevents my MessageBox from opening at all.

Is there a way to disregard Domain.UnhandledException at this point since the app is technically supposed to be shutting down already?

Answer (score 0):

The `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` and `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` events may be raised from several threads so you want to make these event handlers thread-safe by introducing a synchronization primitive such as a lock:

```
private readonly object _lock = new object();
private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        //one one thread at a time can enter this critical section
        MessageBox.Show("An error occured...");
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
}
```